ksoftirqd нагрузка CPU
Я обнаружил, что процесс [ksoftirqd/0] нагружает мой процессор.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, из за чего это может быть и как решить проблему
- OC: Debian 11
Информация из /proc/interrupts:


Сейчас на 7.5%
У меня есть проблема, раз в 1-2 недели к выделенному серверу пропадает соединение на 10-15 секунд, в логах пусто, с оборудованием всё в порядке, менял выделенные сервера несколько раз, считаю, что нагружается процессор.
На другом сервере нет такой проблемы, так же там нет нагрузки от ksoftirqd. Я лишь сегодня начал мониторить нагрузку, буду смотреть что происходит в момент проблемы. Просто посчитал что вполне возможно ksoftirqd нагружает процессор на 100% и из за этого возникает проблема.
Поэтому хотел узнать, из за чего он нагружает и как можно диагностировать это

Все уточнения в тело вопроса пожалуйста
